# How can I hide specific cells in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to hide a specific cell in SSRS based on row number or group value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" a cell? If a cell is hidden, and it's part of a column/row the table would end up malformed. It be better to `NULL` the value based on your logic. If you need to hide things, you do so to, rows, column, groups or objects in SSRS; not a single cell.

Comment: Here's the issue, let's say i have a table that contains 3 columns, Company, Department and Employees, the columns company and Department are grouped but the Employees column isn't, now i want to hide the employee names that are under the IT department

Comment: So you don't want to hide cells, you want to hide rows?

Comment: No that's the issue, I want to hide the Employees that are in the IT department, but show the employees that are in the HR department, I apologize if I'm not making it clear enough

Comment: Add a `WHERE` to your SQL? `WHERE DeptName != 'IT'`.

Comment: Please check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966446/6923146

Comment: Like @Larnu said. This would be easier if you just modify the query and not the report.